# What are ways of creating persistent values with Google Sheets API?

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, urlfetch

I am writing a Google Sheet google script program. Multiple `UrlFetch` calls get data that I would like to be stored somewhere and accessed later (without the need to call UrlFetch again). I have tried multiple ways to preserve information beyond a single run of a function. Based on my research:

- global variables inside .gs files are redefined each time a function is called. Not fitting to store persistent values
- `PropertiesService` allows storing text string... but my data quickly outgrew it.
- So I started storing in Sheets inside the spreadsheet, and I believe my data outgrew the spreadsheet file as well (past the 15th tab or so I get an exception when I try to run my function again). [is there a way to get the size of your file? - just so I can verify the 5million cell limit is reached?]
- My next go-to now would be to create files on Google Drive.

Is that the way to proceed? Do you think I should store data inside another Spreadsheet file or in a text file or something? JSON file?

Comment: How much of a reduction in data storage would you get if you processed it immediately after each fetch?

Comment: You need to bite the bullet and get an SQL server.  There are free MySQL servers that will allow you to store up to 5GB in the cloud.  You won't regret it.  I did exactly what you're talking about doing but at the end of the day storing the data in a sheet is not nearly as speedy or as easy as SQL.  Pretty much changed my life.

Comment: Or, without bias towards RDBMs, use a noSQL database, especially given the fact that Google closely integrated with Firebase. Also, Cloud Storage buckets could be of use.

Comment: Also, it would be nice if we could see what the project is about - maybe we can suggest other ways to optimize beyond switching to a database / cloud storage. It is hard to give you advice on how to proceed if we do not know what your circumstances are.

Comment: Thank you for all the advice. @Oleg Valter - I am playing with AlphaVantage. Making calls for stock quotes. Using the importJSON function https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON. Each call usually gets me much more data than I need. But since I do not want to 'waste' a call I want to store the data.  Never did anything with servers...  Google Drive sounds a bit less intimidating (I would hope it would be easily accessible with the google script i am already in) - is it bad for storing or just slower than SQL? Does SQL still work with file types?

Comment: @makmak - well, you are not obliged to know SQL or use an RDBMS database at all, it is a matter of preference (you can use a noSQL-type database and get the same results using whatever language you like). For that matter, you can store plaintext files (literally .txt) and it will work just fine. The problem with using GDrive or GSheets for *acting* as a database is, yes, slowness and quotas, because they are not intended to act as databases. Do check [Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/products/storage)